# HiddenField's value set using JQuery, but value cannot be read in the code-behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here's my HTML code

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>
         Department Comments:
     </th>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartmentComments" runat="server" Columns = "45" 
              TextMode = "MultiLine" CssClass = "txtComments" ></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfDptComments" runat = "server" />

     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat="server" Text="Completed" 
          CssClass = "button-save" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$('[id*="btnComplete"]').click(function () {
    var $val = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id*="txtDepartmentComments"]').val();
    var hfDptComments = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id*="hfDptComments"]');
    $(hfDptComments).prop('value', $val);

    alert($(hfDptComments).val());
});
```

And this is just a dummy code to test whether the value is being sent to the server.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string strDptComments = this.hfDptComments.Value;
}
```

When I type something and run the application, the javascript box message is showing me what I typed. However, when I put a break point in the code behind, I always get an empty string.

Any idea why?

Thanks for helping

Comment: note that `Page_Load` is being called _before_ running the javascript which is setting the hiddenfield; if a submit is going to happen (via a button or any control that posts back) after javascript populates the value, you _will_ get the value

Comment: @mshsayem He probably is clicking a button that does postback as well, and the page_load will be called again... so i doubt that's the issue.

Comment: The reason I am avoiding putting markup directly in the code is because the controls, i.e. button, textarea, and hiddenfield are located inside a user control which is located inside a repeater. Thus,markup will be long and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting the value using `.val()` instead

```
$(hfDptComments).val($val);
```

Comment: still no luck. strDptComments is still an empty string.

Comment: Now I have the feeling that this issue has nothing to do with JQuery. That's must be the way ASP.NET works. Those controls, i.e. button, textarea, and hiddenfield are located inside a user control which is located inside a repeater. When the page posts back, for reason still unknown, no values can be read in the code-behind.

Comment: @Richard77 can you post the entire aspx page and the entire codebehind? i think this will really help

Comment: As I said, that had to do with ASP.Net. Now that I'm checking which control contains the button that caused the postback, things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
hfDptComments.prop('value', $val);

hfDptComments.attr('value', $val);

hfDptComments.val($val);
```

`hfDptComments` its already a jquery object. try one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Write your javascript function normally (without event binding via jQuery) like:

```
function SetMyValue() {
    var $val = $('#<%# btnComplete.ClientID %>').closest('tr').find('[id*="txtDepartmentComments"]').val();
    var hfDptComments = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id*="hfDptComments"]');
    $(hfDptComments).val($val);
}
```

Set `OnclientClick` attribute in the markup of the button (which is going to postback) like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat="server" Text="Completed" OnClientClick="return SetMyValue();"
          CssClass = "button-save" />
```